# Is it possilbe to setup your local environment with packer (like with ansible playbook)

Tags: linux, ansible, packer, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to setup my development environment (**on my local Linux pc**) via some automatic mechanism.
I tried ansible playbooks, they work quite well.

Let's assume a playbook like this ("SetupDevEnv.yml")

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: install packages
      apt:
        state: present
        name:
         - gcc
         - clang
         - vscode
         - ...
```

After running :

```
$ ansible-playbook SetupDevEnv.yml
```

My local pc is ready to go with all the toolchain tools needed (gcc, clang, vscode, ...).

Is it possible to do the same thing with [packer](https://www.packer.io/)?
If yes, how would it look like?
Would it also be possible to use the existing Ansible playbooks?

**Remark1:** The important point here is I want to do it for **my local pc (localhost) only**. I do not want to generate a VM or a Docker container to which I have to log in afterward.
The idea is: the "SetupDevEnv.yml" (or the packer file) is located in the repository. The developer checks out the repository runs the setup generation and starts to work.

**Remark2:** To clarify the question, my question is: "How would the packer HCL/json file look like to do the same as in "SetupDevEnv.yml"? Or how would the packer HCL/json file look like which uses the "SetupDevEnv.yml"? If this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Supposing you're installing Packer using the APT repositories provided by Hashicorp on Ubuntu 20.04, that could be accomplished with the following playbook:

```yaml
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Add Hashicorp's GPG key
      apt_key:
        state: present
        url: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg

    - name: Add Hashicorp's repository
      apt_repository:
        mode: 0644
        repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
      
    - name: Install Packer
      apt:
        name: packer
        state: present
```

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you. But this is just a ansible playbook to install packer, or? Or can one use your *.yml file above in packer?
How would the packer HCL/json file look like to do the same as in "SetupDevEnv.yml"? Or how to include the "SetupDevEnv.yml" into the packer file?

Comment: This is a full playbook. To append it to your `SetupDevEnv.yml`, you could just copy/paste the modules part into it. =)